# Creating a favourite checkbox in a list, Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm hoping to create a checkbox for items that I have in a list.

I was looking at applying this by using a boolean value for my items i.e if attribute 'favourite' = true, then checkbox is highlighted and vice versa if false.

Unfortunately, so far I am unsure of the logic for this and how to connect it to my view (Checkbox).

My view is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:elevation="24dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageIcon"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/change_hike_image"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hikeName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="A Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.052"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hikeName"
            tools:text="A Description" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/favourite"
            style="?android:attr/starStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Adapter:

```
package org.wit.hikingtrails.adapters

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import org.wit.hikingtrails.databinding.CardHikeBinding
import org.wit.hikingtrails.models.HikeModel

interface HikeListener {
    fun onHikeClick(hike: HikeModel)
}

class HikeAdapter constructor(private var hikes: List<HikeModel>,
                              private val listener: HikeListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<HikeAdapter.MainHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MainHolder {
        val binding = CardHikeBinding
            .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return MainHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MainHolder, position: Int) {
        val hike = hikes[holder.adapterPosition]
        holder.bind(hike, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = hikes.size

    class MainHolder(private val binding : CardHikeBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        fun bind(hike: HikeModel, listener: HikeListener) {
            binding.hikeName.text = hike.name
            binding.description.text = hike.description
            binding.favourite.text = hike.favourite.toString()

            if (hike.image != ""){
                Picasso.get()
                    .load(hike.image)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .into(binding.imageIcon)
            }
            binding.root.setOnClickListener { listener.onHikeClick(hike) }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
package org.wit.hikingtrails.views.hikeList

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import org.wit.hikingtrails.R
import org.wit.hikingtrails.adapters.HikeAdapter
import org.wit.hikingtrails.adapters.HikeListener
//import org.wit.hikingtrails.databinding.ActivityHikeListBinding
import org.wit.hikingtrails.main.MainApp
import org.wit.hikingtrails.models.HikeModel
import android.content.Intent
import android.view.*
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import org.wit.hikingtrails.databinding.ActivityHikeListBinding
import org.wit.hikingtrails.views.BaseView
import timber.log.Timber

class HikeListView :  BaseView(), HikeListener {

    lateinit var app: MainApp
    lateinit var binding: ActivityHikeListBinding
    lateinit var presenter: HikeListPresenter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHikeListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.toolbar.title = title
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

        presenter = HikeListPresenter(this)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

        updateRecyclerView()
    }

//    override fun showHikes(hikes: List<HikeModel>) {
//        recyclerView.adapter = HikeAdapter(hikes, this)
//        recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
//    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        //update the view
        super.onResume()
        updateRecyclerView()
        binding.recyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        Timber.i("recyclerView onResume")

    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            R.id.item_add -> presenter.doAddHike()
            R.id.item_map -> presenter.doShowHikesMap()
            R.id.logout -> presenter.doLogout()
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onHikeClick(hike: HikeModel) {
        presenter.doEditHike(hike)
    }

    private fun updateRecyclerView(){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main){
            binding.recyclerView.adapter =
                HikeAdapter(presenter.getHikes(), this@HikeListView)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `favorite` property to your `HikeModel` like this

```kotlin
data class HikeModel(
  ... code
  // use mutable property bcs you will update it later when checkbox is checked or uncheck.
  var favorite: Boolean = false // false by default
)
```

and then

```kotlin
fun bind(hike: HikeModel, listener: HikeListener) {
            ...
            binding.favourite.isChecked = hike.favorite
            binding.favourite.setOnClickListener {
               hike.favorite = binding.favourite.isChecked
               listener.onHikeClick(hike)
            }
            ...
        }
```